# Server is giving 404 error in the server not in the localhost if .htaccess file is written properly

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

cakephp/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine on
    # Uncomment if you have a .well-known directory in the app folder, e.g. for the Let's Encrypt challenge
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    #RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

cakephp/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine on
    # Uncomment if you have a .well-known directory in the root folder, e.g. for the Let's Encrypt challenge
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    #RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

cakephp/app/webRoot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

mode_rewrite also enabled.Path also correct then also server is giving 404 not error.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="/css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="/css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

None of the css and js files are loading.only cakephp css is loading.I changed the ownership of the file to root and and i have give the 775 file permission to app/tmp also

Comment: Please check if `.htaccess` file exists on the server, Sometimes they get missed as hidden files

Comment: "only cakephp css is loading" - `cakephp.css`(?) isn't even referenced in the code you have posted? Is `cakephp` a subdirectory in `cakephp/.htaccess`? If so then your CSS URLs are not influcenced by the `.htaccess` files you have posted? Except the first one which is relative.

Comment: yes i checked that also .htaccess file is present in server also.And i changed the permission for webroot to 775 also

Comment: no it is not a subdirectory.Everything is running perfectly in the local.But css and js is not loading in server

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? So, `cakephp` is the document root?  In your local environment do you have the same directory structure? In all 3 of the `.htaccess` files you've posted you have set `RewriteBase /` - which does not look correct (but this would have presumably failed when tested locally as well??).

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: Cakephp is my document Root.I am using cakephp 2.9.7. Now I commented RewriteBase then also it is working.It is having no effect on .htaccess for me

Comment: Is `/cakephp` a sub-directory in your server root -or THE server root?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake i am new to cakephp.In cakephp all the css js files should be placed in app/webroot but i placed them root folder itself.when i placed the files in webroot www can access it.Thank you for your help.